# Node.JS https request return JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, https

I have a question about the Node.js HTTPS request.
The request goes to a server,which will return a JSON response. Then I want to parse the response and store it in a variable and use it with other functions.

```
let obj=JSON.parse(response);
return obj;
```

The functions I have written:

```
let protocol="https";
let hostStr="www.example.com";
let pathStr="***";

let students=makeRequest("ABCDEFG","getStudents"));
console.log(students);

function makeRequest(token,method){    
       let obj='';
        let options={
            host:hostStr,
            path:pathStr,
            method:"POST",
            headers:{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID="+token}
        };
        let https=require(protocol);
        callback = function(response){
            var str='';

            response.on('data',function(chunk){
                str+=chunk;
            });

            response.on('end',function(){
                obj=JSON.parse(str);
            });
        }
        let request=https.request(options,callback);
        request.write('{"id":"ID","method":"'+method+'","params":{},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}');
        request.end();
        return obj;
    }
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do what you want you need to understand the asynchrone side of Javascript. What you do can't work because the string is updated in an asynchronous callback. I have fix the part that didn't work.

```js
let protocol="https";
let hostStr="www.example.com";
let pathStr="***";

makeRequest("ABCDEFG","getStudents"))
  .then(students => {
      // here is what you want
      console.log(students);  
  });


function makeRequest(token,method){    
  return new Promise(resolve => {
        let obj='';
        let options={
            host:hostStr,
            path:pathStr,
            method:"POST",
            headers:{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID="+token}
        };
        let https=require(protocol);
        callback = function(response){
            var str='';

            response.on('data',function(chunk){
                str+=chunk;
            });

            response.on('end',function(){
                obj=JSON.parse(str);
                resolve(obj);
            });
        }
        let request = https.request(options,callback);
        request.write('{"id":"ID","method":"'+ method +'","params":{},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}');
        request.end();
  });
}
```

[Here you can read more about asynchonous in javascript](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now I have a new Problem
I have to get a token wait until I received it and then do the rest of my code.
But I can't get it to wait until the server responded to my request. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make the next request inside the callback of the first request, but I suggest you to look async functions they may help you a lot. And check librairies like request-promise.